# Is there a way to sort this Google scripts function numerically/opposite direction?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Here is the script that I'm using to pull all the sheet names of a Google Sheet Document into a list on a front sheet.  It is working; however, is there a way to sort this the opposite way?  I have the sheets named by date with the oldest date as the furthest sheet and the newest sheet the closest to the front.  So it is sorting the newest date first but I would like it to sort with the oldest date first.  Also, is there a way to make this function dynamic so it updates as new sheets are added or if the sheet names change?

```
function sheetnames() {
  var out = new Array()
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();


for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) {
  Logger.log(String(sheets[i].getSheetId()));
 // var sheetId = sheets.getSheetId()
  out.push( [ sheets[i].getName() ] ) 
}

return out 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse):

```
function sheetnamesreverse() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .getSheets()
    .map(s => [s.getName()])
    .reverse();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `onChange` [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions), but take into consideration its [Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions). In this way, the code I will be providing you, it will run every time you add a new sheet or you edit a sheet's name:

```
// Installable Trigger
function onChange() {
  var dates = sheetNames();
  Logger.log(dates);
}

function sheetNames(){
  try{
    // Get all sheets and then return
    return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
             .getSheets()
             // Get a new array only with the sheet names
             .map(function(sheet){ return sheet.getName() })
             // Sort the array from the oldest date to the newest date
             .sort(
               function (sheet1, sheet2){
                 return new Date(sheet2) - new Date(sheet1);
               });
  } catch(e){
    Logger.log("Not a date");
    return e;
  }
}
```

Now, for setting up the installable trigger, do the following:

1) Go to your Apps Script project

2) Click Edit->Current project's triggers

3) Click "+ Add Trigger"

4) Select :

Choose which function to run ->

Select event source-> From spreadsheet

Select event type -> On change

5) Click Save